# Display image with Pug/Jade and node.js

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I want to display an avatar of the logged user in the navbar, but everytime I get error 404 with the URL: 
`http://localhost:3000/uploads/avatars/avatar_test3.jpeg`
my pug code is:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
        if user
          li
            a(href='/photos/add') Add photo
          li
            a(href='/users/edit')
              img(src=user.avatar)
          li
            a(href='/users/logout') Logout
```

`user.avatar` gives me: `uploads/avatars/avatar_test3.jpeg`
I have also tried with the:

- `img(src='../' + user.avatar)`
- `img(src='./' + user.avatar)`
- `img(src='/' + user.avatar)`

The same error every time

The directory hierarchy:

```
/
 -uploads
    -avatars
       -avatar_test3.jpeg
  -views
    -layout/pug //the template I'm using
```

I also have tried with move the avatar_test3.jpeg file directly to the view directory but without any success.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What is the **exact** error that you are getting?  You didn't post an error, you posted a url.  Are you using express?  Have you read through [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)?  Post the node.js code that actually does stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake, I added type of error.
@Darian helped me great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which error are you getting? If it is http 404, you should turn your uploads folder public through express: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Something like:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))
```

Comment: it works great! I totally forgot about that, thank you!